# Meteor.users information from collection helpers

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get some information via the collection-helpers package for non-logged in users and I'm obviously missing something fundamental here as I'm getting nowhere.

I have a relationship set up what is happily returning the profile.name element for the owner of a document, as long as that happens to coincide with the logged in user, but, I'm getting nothing back for non-logged in users (because of the security on the client side).

I've added a new publication on both client and server as

```
// User Profile
Meteor.publish("userProfile", function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
    {fields: {'profile': 1}});
});
```

and have subscribed to this publication in the js associated with the page I'm trying to display it in

```
// Don't need this to be reactive, so
Meteor.subscribe("userProfile");
```

but am still not getting access to the profile data in the document with

```
<h4>Posted by: {{projOwner.profile.name}}</h4>
```

where projOwner looks like

```
projectDocs.helpers({
  projOwner: function() {
    console.log(this.owner._id);
    var owner = Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner._id);
    //console.log("Owner is: " +owner);
    return owner;
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a publish function, `this.userId` is always the id of the currently logged in user. The profile of the current user is automatically published so that function doesn't do anything useful.

The real problem here is you need to get the correct subset of users published to the client. Maybe that's the project owner of the document you are looking at, maybe it's a all of the users in a group, etc. Without knowing more about your problem it's hard to say.

An easy place to start with is just publishing all of the users to make sure your code works, and then try reducing the set. Remember that publish functions can take arguments, so you could pass in, for example, the id of a project and then publish the owner like so:

```js
Meteor.publish('projectOwner', function(projectId) {
  check(projectId, String);
  var project = Projects.findOne(projectId);
  return Meteor.users.find(project.owner, {
    fields: {'profile': 1}
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks David, this is driving me nuts. I have added this to the publication:
Meteor.publish('itemOwner', function(userId) {
  check(userId, String);
  return Meteor.users.find(userId, {
    fields: {'profile': 1}
  });
});
and in the template

        {{owner._id}}
        {{owner.createdAt}}
        {{owner.profile.name}}
I get the correct id, but nothing else seems to be getting passed back. (sorry about the formatting, not sure what to do about that in here)

Comment: Got it... needed to get the subscription correct (was using the wrong name because I changed it) and it started working.  THANKS.